# jQuery DatePicker does not render beforeShowDay after initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am working on a booking system for a hotel. I want the booking system to be like the one on acehotel.com. Mine works, but when I click on "Uitcheck dag" (day of checking out) it does not show the day of checking in. Here is a link to my page: http://webdesign.kam-online.net/DatePicker/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var dates = [];
var dateArray = [];

currentDate = new Date();

var tips  = ['some description','some other description'];
$("#aantallen").hide();
$("#datepicker").hide();
$("#datepicker2").hide();

$("#AantalMensen").click(function(){
    $("#datepicker2").hide();
    $("#datepicker").hide();
    $("#aantallen").show();
});

$("#IncheckDag").click(function(){
    $("#datepicker2").hide();
    $("#aantallen").hide();
    $("#datepicker").show();
});

$("#UitcheckDag").click(function(){
    $("#datepicker").hide();
    $("#aantallen").hide();   
    $("#datepicker2").show();
});

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    return dat;
}

function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {


    var currentDate = startDate;

    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push( new Date (currentDate) );
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    }
    return dateArray;
}

$('#datepicker').datepicker({                
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    onSelect: function () {

        var pickedDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");

        if (pickedDate > currentDate) {
            dates.push(pickedDate);
            dateArray.push(pickedDate);
            alert(dates[0]);

        } else {
            alert("Error");
        }

    }
});

$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    onSelect: function () {

        var pickedSecondDate = $("#datepicker2").datepicker("getDate");

        if (pickedSecondDate > dates[0])
        {
            dates.push(pickedSecondDate);
            alert(dates[1]);
            var start = dates[0];
            var end = dates[1];
            getDates(start, end);
        } else {
            alert("Error");
        }
    }
});



function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(dateArray[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {              
            return [true, 'highlight', tips[i]];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing an error in the below code snippet in your HTML( Function searchRoom())

```
document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Aantal Volwassenen " + volwassenen + "<br>\
      Aantal Kinderen " + kinderen + "<br>\
      Incheck Datum " + checkinDate + "<br>\
      Uitcheck Datum " + checkoutDate + "<br
```

it is not properly ended.

```
document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Aantal Volwassenen " + volwassenen + "<br>\
      Aantal Kinderen " + kinderen + "<br>\
      Incheck Datum " + checkinDate + "<br>\
      Uitcheck Datum " + checkoutDate + "<br>";
```

Try this once

Comment: Well, I was just working on that :D The problem is when I select a checkin date and click check out date, it does not highlight the checkin date. Thanks for the answer.